# CSS Float In IE7 Document Standard

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float, internet-explorer-6

I am using this YAML page([fullpage_grids.html](http://www.yaml.de/fileadmin/examples/07_layouts_advanced_2/fullpage_grids.html)) as template to ramp up a page.

The problem is: In IE7, the bottom 3 DIVs which are supposed to be horizontally aligned now vertically stacked together.

Can you give me a fix to this page?

Comment: Probably due to IE7's support of inline-block being incomplete....

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC How can I fix it?

Comment: It doesn't appear that inline-block is used. Also, I set my IE8 to IE7 mode and the bottom 3 divs appear correctly, horizontally aligned.

Comment: It's setting the layout as a CSS nested table as `table` and `table-cell`; not `inline-block`.

Comment: @Dean Burge I test this in three computers with different OSes, different resolution. Set IE8 Document Modes to IE7 standard via developer tool: Document Mode -> IE7 standard. Not browser mode.

Comment: Set Browser mode to IE8, document standard to IE7 can see this problem. I am not trying to deliberately break the layout, it turns out that everything works fine locally until I upload my page to SharePoint server, it messed up. looks exactly like set document standard to IE7.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a float problem it's a table problem. Are you making the cells expand?

container/row

```
.equalize,
.equalize .subcolumns {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.subcolumns {
  display: table;
}
```

columns/cells

```
.equalize > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC Cool, then there is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw another answer out there...

Quirksmode has a list of the compatibility for the display declaration
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

If you absolutely need the layout to work in IE7, you could think about using a table or possibly a horizontal unordered list